# Show the author's count of total amount of posts assign to a custom taxonomy term

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, author, count

I have assigned a custom taxonomy named `Highlight` to posts and I have added a term to it named `Featured`.

Whenever I want to feature a post, I simply assign it to featured.

To each author, I want to display their count of total amount of featured posts.

So the function `the_author_posts()` will display count of total posts. I want to display count of total posts that were featured to the author.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Get the author post count for a tax query.
 *
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/159160/1685
 *
 * @param   array   $tax_query
 * @return  int
 */
function wpse_159160_get_author_posts_by_tax( $tax_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, get_post()->post_author );

    $tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
    $sql = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

    return ( int ) $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts {$sql['join']} $where {$sql['where']}" );
}
```

And in use:

```
$count = wpse_159160_get_author_posts_by_tax(
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'highlight',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
            'field'    => 'slug',
        )
    )
);

echo "$count Featured Posts";
```

If you wanted less control with the function (& neater template code), you could hardcode the `$tax_query` argument inside the function and just call it without arguments elsewhere.

Comment: To clarify. Can I change the get_post()-> post_author to a custom user id like current user's id?

Comment: Of course - just use `get_current_user_id()` instead. If you want to vary it, add a `$user_id` argument to the function and then call it as required.